# Django choice field is not returning data through API endpoints

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a custom User model and Profile model.
In the Profile model I have 4 attributes:

1. owner - OnetoOne relation with CustomUser
2. gender - IntegerField with choices tuple. ie: (1, 'Male'), default=1
3. city - CharField
4. country - CharField

The serializer is defined with `'__all__'` fields.
But the API endpoint is returning:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "city": null,
    "country": null
}
```

What I'm expecting from the API to return is all the fields defined in Profile Model.
like this:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    //Here I'm expecting the owners(CustomUser) Fields under user key
    "gender": 1,
    "city": null,
    "country": null

}
```

for better understanding please take a look at the code.

My Custom User model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="avatars/", null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomBaseUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Profile Model:

```
GENDERS = (
    (1, 'Male'),
    (2, 'Female'),
    (3, 'Other'),
)
class Profile(models.Model):
    """Model for users profile"""
    owner = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomUser, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name='profile'
    )
    gender = models.IntegerField(_('Gender'), default=1, choices=GENDERS)
    city = models.CharField(_('City'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(_('Country'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'profile-{self.id}-{self.owner.get_full_name()}'
```

Profile Serializer:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for retrieve update and delete profile"""
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('owner', )
```

Profile API view:

```
class ProfileAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(User, id=self.request.user.id, is_active=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `get_gender_display` function in the serializer.

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    gender = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('owner', )

    def get_gender(self, obj):
        return obj.get_gender_display()
```

Comment: I've tried that. But it throws error saying CustomUser doesn't have attribute get_gender_display. For your info: My Profile has a OneToOne relation with my CustomUser. Can you please take a look into my CustomUser one more time please?
I've tried so many options but couldn't quite solve it.